# ¿Cómo reestablezco la contraseña en mysql 8.1?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hace un tiempo instale mysql workbench 8.1, lo dejé de usar y al momento de querer usarlo de nuevo me di cuenta de que olvidé la contraseña, ¿Hay manera de ver la contraseña que puse? o ¿Cómo la reestablezco? he buscado, pero todas la soluciones son a través de la linea de comandos, a la cual no tengo acceso porque no se la contraseña.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias

Comment: ¿Asignaste una contraseña al usuario `root`? Si no ha sido esa contraseña la que has perdido, intenta acceder como `root` sin contraseña. En cambio, si fue esa la contraseña perdida, en el [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) está explicado cómo resetar la contraseña del usuario `root`. Revisa el apartado **B.3.3.2.1 Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems** si estás trabajando en Windows, o bien el apartado **B.3.3.2.2 Resetting the Root Password: Unix and Unix-Like Systems** si trabajas en un entorno basado en Unix o similar.

Answer (score -1):

Solo tienes que seguir estos pasos:

1. Abre MySQL Workbench y conecta al servidor para el que deseas
   cambiar la contraseña.
2. En la pestaña de "Navigator" (Navegador), selecciona la instancia
   del servidor.
3. En la sección "Management" (Gestión), elige "Users and Privileges"
   (Usuarios y Privilegios).
4. Selecciona el usuario para el que deseas cambiar la contraseña.
5. En la pestaña "Login/Administration" (Inicio/Administración),
   encontrarás la opción para cambiar la contraseña. Puedes ingresar la
   nueva contraseña y confirmarla.
6. Haz clic en "Apply" (Aplicar) para guardar los cambios

Puedes ver los pasos en mayor detalle con este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivmY43PdXbw)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).